# How to display looping data in codeigniter 3 in 1 line

Tags: bootstrap-4, foreach, codeigniter-3

I want to create a list of hotel rooms using bootstrap, and display them sequentially 1 line.

**View**

```
<h2>Gate A</h2>

  <?php
      $no = 1;
      foreach ($tamu as $tamu) : 
    ?>

   <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo $tamu->gateA ?></button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">3</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">4</button>
    </div>
   </div>

  <?php endforeach;?>
```

The green button is the data from the database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YG6x.png)

Comment: If you want each room on a single line, just use [bootstrap grid systems](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) and put each room into one `<div class="row">put room here</div>`

Comment: This was solved yesterday. Btw, thanks for the response